# AWS Cognito Invalid login token error with my token from Developer authentication

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I want to put object to AWS S3 directly from browser on angular js.
For this, I use cognito developer authentication.
I got cognito identity id and token from my rails server.

With that token(I think it is valid), my put action is rejected from AWS S3 : **Invalid login token.**
**I don't know why..**

Here is my code.

```
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  AccountId: '0000',
  IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:0000-0000-0000',
  RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::0000:role/myRoleName',
  Logins: {
    'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com': 'token from cognito.get_open_id_token_for_developer_identity'
  }
});
var bucket = new AWS.S3({ params: { Region: 'ap-northeast-1', Bucket: 'my bucket name' }});
```

(0000 parts are just sample)
I wonder there is **no space for 'identity_id'** from cognito.get_open_id_token_for_developer_identity.
**Config regioin and s3 region are different** because I use tokyo S3 but n.virginia Cognito.

++ I added s3 full access to Managed Policies in my role(myRoleName), and added below setting to Inline policy. (I also added 'resource * version of below setting' to Inline policy)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "0000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::myBucketName"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use the "Basic authflow". Here is a link to our documentation on auth flows: 
 http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/concepts/authentication-flow/#developer-authenticated-identities-authflow

This is not using the token you are providing in the logins map.

I recommend using the "Enhanced authflow". To do this:
(1) Make sure your identity pool is configured with the roles you wish your users to use: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/concepts/iam-roles/

(2) Remove the AccountId and RoleArn arguments to the identity constructor.

Comment: I tried for enhanced authflow but using basic authflow method. Now I know what's going on, and it works! thank you!